# Why doesn't onChanged in Office JS for Excel have sheet name

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am trying to get the sheet name of the cell changed in Office JS in Excel. However, in the function that handles onChanged, when I `console.log(event)`, this is the result (in the picture).

[image]

Why would they include sheet id in the event but not sheet name? Or there is sheet name of the changed cell somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, onChanged event currently provides worksheetId but not worksheet name, as the worksheet name can be retrieved via `getItem(worksheetId)`.

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;

    const sheet = sheets.getItem(worksheetId);
    sheet.load("name");

    await context.sync();
    console.log(sheet.name);

}
```

However, this event will not be trigger when worksheet name is changed.
If you would like to be notified when the worksheet is renamed. we have a work item on `worksheetNameChanged` event, team is working on it, it will soon be previewed.

Comment: just curious about the reasons why your team decided to include sheeet id but not sheet name in the event object? Do people use sheet id more often than sheet name?

Comment: because sheet name may be change， but sheet id is GUID, it won't be changed